# How to perform an 'OR' query with S4S connector?

Tags: salesforce, sitecore

I'm trying figure out how to query Salesforce with multiple filters where either filter can be true (similar to a traditional `WHERE x='' OR y=''` SQL statement).

The following appears works, but produces an 'AND' query where both filters must be true:

```
var dataSource = new GenericSalesforceEntityDataSource("Download__c", GetSalesforceSession);
dataSource.AddDataSourceFilter("Contact__c", new Operator(ComparisonOperator.Equals), profile.ContactId);
dataSource.AddDataSourceFilter("Lead__c", new Operator(ComparisonOperator.Equals), profile.LeadId);
var downloads = dataSource.GetQueryResultsAsEntities();
```

I would like to avoid hard-coding SOQL queries into my .NET application, if possible. Does the S4S API support these sorts of queries, or should I be using SOQL for this?

Comment: SOQL would make this much easier, in the Salesforce UI you generally can specify rules to AND together, or if you want more special logic you enable an extra field where you write out the logic using the rule numbers, for example (1 AND (2 OR 3)). There may be some way of specifying this on the dataSource, but I'm not familiar with the APIs you're using (generally work on salesforce directly).

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. I was able to specify the 'OR' SOQL query within the API and it worked!

Comment: Posted as an answer for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOQL would make this much easier so that should be the route you choose if available to you, especially since it offers the easiest way to perform logical operations with your filters.

Answer (score 3):

The [Sitecore for Salesforce Connector (S4S)](http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/S4S.aspx) has composite filters that allow you to programmatically create a DataSource that is converted into a SOQL query with OR operators in the where clause.

```
var dataSource = new GenericSalesforceEntityDataSource("Download__c", GetSalesforceSession);
var orFilter = new LogicalDisjunctionFilter();
orFilter.AddDataSourceFilter("Contact__c", ComparisonOperator.Equals, profile.ContactId);
orFilter.AddDataSourceFilter(ApexLog.Fields.Location, ComparisonOperator.Equals, "SystemLog");
// The two filters above will be combined with a logical OR
dataSource.AddDataSourceFilter(orFilter);
var downloads = dataSource.GetQueryResultsAsEntities();
```

You can use combinations of the LogicalDisjunctionFilter with the LogicalConjunctionFilter to build up AND and OR logic as required.

Alternatively, you could directly add the SOQL where clause to the datasource.

```
var dataSource = new GenericSalesforceEntityDataSource("Download__c", GetSalesforceSession);
dataSource.SoqlFilter = string.Format("Contact__c = '{0}' OR Location = 'SystemLog'", profile.ContactId);
var downloads = dataSource.GetQueryResultsAsEntities();
```

Or, as Matt suggests, you could build up your own SOQL string and run that directly.

```
var dataSource = new GenericSalesforceEntityDataSource("Download__c", GetSalesforceSession);
var queryResult = dataSource.RunSoqlQuery(new SoqlQuery(string.Format("Select Id from Download__c where Contact__c = '{0}' OR Location = 'SystemLog'", profile.ContactId)));
var downloads = dataSource.EntitysFromQueryResult<GenericSalesforceEntity>(queryResult);
```

Comment: @DerekHunziker I'm more than happy to answer S4S questions on StackOverflow, though I'm afraid I was a bit late in getting to this one. Feel free to contact FuseIT for any S4S support questions.